# Compare 2 arrays of groups

Tags: php, arrays

So basically I got 2 arrays of groups which I need to compare.
But it always returns 'FALSE', any idea?

```
function QuickGroupCompare()
{
    $pre = '2,3,4';
    $groupids = '10,5,6,3,4,2,18,1';

    $l_Group = explode(",", $pre);
    $m_Group = explode(",", $groupids);

    foreach ($l_Group as $index => $i_x)
    {
        if ($i_x == $m_Group[$index])
            return 'CORRECT';
    }

    return 'FALSE';
}
echo QuickGroupCompare();
```

Comment: What do you want as your output? Are you looking for everything in `$pre` to exist in `$groupids` to return '`CORRECT`'?

Comment: I want that if there is just 1 match to return 'CORRECT' yes

Comment: You are checked to see if i_x is equal to the value at the same position (index). Is this intended? Or do you want to see if i_x exists at all in the other group?

Comment: It currently compares the position of the value in the other string. Do you want to return CORRECT if it is anywhere in the other string?

Comment: Yes SArnab I want to know if it exists in the other group

Comment: Yes Tristan thats exactly what I want

Comment: your current groups aren't arrays at all. Make them as such and compare them. There are quite a few (PHP) functions already made up for it

Comment: Then you should checkout `array_search()`

Comment: Can you give me an example? Because I only find examples with 1 array, but I have 2.

Comment: Robbie posted a solution for you below. If it solves what you want, consider accepting his answer.

Comment: Already responded to his answer, I get a weird error, although amazing of him to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simply determine whether one of the numbers in `$a` exists in `$b` you can use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

```
function compare($a, $b)
{
    return !empty(array_intersect($a, $b));
}
```

[Example](https://eval.in/599979):

```
var_dump(compare($l_Group, $m_Group));              // true
var_dump(compare($l_Group, explode(',', '6,7,8'))); // false
```

Convert the boolean result to 'CORRECT' or 'FALSE' after the function call, it's better to return a boolean in this case from the function itself:

```
$result = compare($a, $b);
echo $result ? 'CORRECT' : 'FALSE';
```

Comment: compare function gives me: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.4 or lower you'll need to use `$common = array_intersect($a, $b); return !empty($common);` to avoid that issue.

Comment: Thanks, I was testing on localhost where I use lower PHP version, again thanks!